# Capybara has_no_css? throws StaleElementReferenceError

Tags: capybara

I am using `has_no_css?` to verify if certain elements are no more visible in UI.

ex:- After clicking 'ok' on confirmation popup, popup should no more be visible in UI. To verify that we use
`page.has_no_css?('.modal.dialog', visible: true)`

Tests failing randomly at has_no_css? with `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up`

I see people talking about this problem in few places(roughly few years old threads)..
https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/578   << Labeled as 'Waiting for response'
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ruby-capybara/O3Ib6INOP58

Currently I am catching this exception to overcome this issue.I would love to hear what are you folks who faced this issue doing/done ? Am I overlooking something and just blindly catching exception ?? suggestions please...

we are using `capybara (2.3.0)`

Comment: Capybara 2.3.0 is pretty old so I would suggest upgrading if possible.  Are your failing expectations being called from inside `#within` blocks?  Can you provide a full stack trace for one of the failures?